# What does the [h+]^3 in the icon mean?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

On the Xbox 360 version of Deus Ex: Human Revolution, on a user's gamercard it shows the following icon to indicate that you've played it recently. I don't know if this image shows up on the PS3 or PC versions.

[image: Gamercard image used for Human Revolution]

Is there a special meaning to this logo? Is it presented somewhere in the game that I missed? I guess I'm just missing the symbolism behind it if there is any, and it could be completely obvious.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"H+" is a symbol commonly used to represent [transhumanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhumanism). This symbol, [cubed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(algebra)), seems to indicate a higher level of transhumanism. It might also be a play on the fact that this is the third game in the series.

Answer (score 10):

Let's break down `[+]³`.

`+` (the  is the unicode `mathematical italic small h` character, `\u+1D455(D835+DC55)`, a specific math glyph) means Human-plus, the next version of man. In the game that means cybernetically augmented people.

The `³` is likely for *Human Revolution* being the third game in the series.

Taken together [+]³ may mean "next-human cubed", as in an exponential advance in humanity as opposed to an iterative advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't listen to the speculations. It's unhealthy.

H+ or h+ is the symbol for transhumanism (the idea of improving the human condition). The "3" simply stands for Deus Ex 3. The reason why H+ is bracketed is because H+^3 is something completely different and they want to (unsuccessfully, it seems) point out the transhuman context.

Fun fact: The whole Daedalus/Icarus dichotomy is based on literature (JBS Hanlane "Daedalus: Or, Science and the Future", in addition to being that famous greek myth).

CyberSkull also makes a lot of sense with the exponent suggestion, since it fits with the theme.

Answer (score 0):

The symbolism (h+) means human-plus(+) and it represents he meaning "transhumanism".

The (h+)3 symbolism means that the (h+) symbolism is being cubed, which means that the
(h+)3 symbolism actually means "advanced transhumanism". I actually don't think that the 3 means that this is the 3rd game of the series because the 3 is shown to cube the symbolism (h+), so that doesn't mean that it represent that it is the 3rd game of the series.

Comment: This seems to be more of a commentary on the previous answers than a standalone answer.